# Watchdog module not found after installing the watchdog package in Ubuntu

Tags: python, watchdog

I am new to ubuntu. Currently I would like to use watchdog package for python script to run in Ubuntu 16.04.1. So I install watchdog package using the following comment:

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
```

Then, I received this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
watchdog is already the newest version (5.14-3ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 485 not upgraded.
```

Then I reboot the ubuntu. When I check is the package installed successfully by using the following comment:

```
apt list --installed
```

However, I don't find watchdog package is installed.

Before installing the watchdog, I also upgrade the packages by using the following comment:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

However, I got this messages:

```
Fetched 6,704 kB in 58s (114 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/di...cons-64x64.tar Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...cons-64x64.tar Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...cons-64x64.tar Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

May I know how can I install watchdog package in ubuntu?

Thank you

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: 16.04.1? I do hope that system is not connected to the open Internet 